# How do I return jsx from an outside function with callback?

Tags: reactjs, callback

I am trying to return jsx from outside my render method. It works when there is no api request, but as soon as I add the request and add a callback I can't return the jsx. How do I do this? renderLocations is being called in my render method.

```
renderLocations() {
    this.Geo((coord) => {
          return this.state.location.map((location, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
               {coord}
              </div>
            );
          })
        })
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious ? What are you returning from `renderLocations` method ? Returning inside callback does not return from the outer scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not do it like this.

A. You are not returning anything from `renderLocations`

B. If you are waiting for some data that will arrive later. Initiate the call in `componentWillMount` lifecycle method and upon arrival update the state of the component using `this.setState({coord: coord})` - this would run the `render` method again. In the render method wherever you are calling the `renderLocations` method pass the `this.state.coord`

And change the renderLocations method like this

```
renderLocations(coord) {
  if (coord) {
    return this.state.location.map((location, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
           {coord}
          </div>
        );
      })
  }
}
```

Also, dont forget to initialize the state in `getInitialState` method or in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you provided, you are not returning anything from your method. I'd suggest you do something like this where you can add `coord` to state.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.Geo((coord) => this.setState({coord});
},

renderLocations() {
  const {coord} = this.state
  return this.state.location.map((location, index) => {
    return (
      <div>
       {coord}
      </div>
    );
  })
}
```

Comment: I would add an `if` to return only if there is coord value set in state else not return anything.